# Presenting MPMoviePlayerViewController not showing navigationBar on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and presenting it using `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:`. This works great on iPhone, but for some reason on iPad I don't get the `navigationBar`, which prevents the user from dismissing the video player. They are now stuck on the video with on way to exit.

Here is how I am loading it:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.moviePlayer];
[self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

Why would this be fine on the iPhone, but not the iPad?

Comment: This code works fine on iPad here: You're aware that the controls disappear and only show up when the user taps on the view?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. This is not the case here.